# Where can I find a simple IBM MQ Client for Windows

Tags: windows, ibm-mq, pymqi

The Context:

I'm hoping I'm missing something simple. I am a novice in IBM MQ

My organisation distributes XML messages via IBM Websphere MQ. Each message represents a record that I simply want to save to a file and clear from the queue.

The current mechanism we have is a poorly understood and overly complex Java program that seems to use both MQ libraries and JMS to do this.

I am hoping to move this to something simpler and easier to maintain, but I can't seem to find a generic 'IBM MQ Client' that can do things like connect to a queue and save the messages. It seems like you have to use binaries or DLLS and build an application around it.

I tried Python as that's closer to my understanding but PyMQI is only for Python 2 (which we don't use) and requires a C compiler which always seems to refuse to work.

The question:

Is there a program out there in windows to simply access a queue and save the messages to a file? We connect periodically so I can just wrap a scheduled task around it.

Comment: If you did a Google search then this page: http://www.capitalware.com/mq_tools_comm.html should have been at the opt of the list.  It contains a very long list of software tools for IBM MQ.  There are many solutions of the list for your problem.  I would suggest you look at MQ Batch Toolkit.  It has an 'Export Message' feature.

Comment: I'd be fascinated to know what search brings that up. I can assure you that every combination of 'IBM mq WebSphere client pre built simple python compiled binary' was tried.

Comment: Ewanw, FYI pymqi supports Python 3.5+ now.

Comment: @JoshMc thanks for letting me know. I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IBM MQ queue manager and clients communicate using a proprietary protocol, so you definitely need to use IBM MQ Client binaries (dlls or lib or jars depending on language you are comfortable with) to put/get messages to/from a queue.

I am sure the JMSToolbox mentioned by @titou10 runs on top of IBM MQ JMS jars.

Comment: you are right. JMSToolBox, as its name implies, uses the JMS protocol to deal with messages on IBM MQ. If the need is to deal with proprietary IBM MQ messages, this is not the right tool. I will amend my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes
If you deal with `JMS` messages in `IBM MQ` then `JMSToolBox` on SourceForge is a tool that will fulfill your needs.
You can download it  [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox)

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question other other self promote your tool on SourceForge.

Comment: @Roger. ? My answer is not an answer the original question asked by the initial poster that was `"Is there a program out there in windows to simply access a queue and save the messages to a file?"` ?? If you deal with IBM MQ via JMS message it exactly answers the question IMHO

Comment: upvoted, that's the same asnwer as accepted, and moreover was done before the accepted answer.